How can i get session information in a server component and client component with next-auth , nextjs
i'm starting with nextjs and use nextauth for authentication on my application . Next-auth apparently manages the session and the token. I want to retrieve the email of the connected user from the data stored in the user's session. this my config files. i'm using the credential provider method . "next": "15.0.0-canary.56" "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.20",
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
 
export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard');
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [], // Add providers with an empty array for now
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import z from 'zod'
import type { User } from '@/app/lib/definitions';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import NextAuthOptions from 'next-auth'

async function getUser(email: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    try {
      const user = await sql<User>`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=${email}`;
      return user.rows[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch user:', error);
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch user.');
    }
  }

export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    Credentials({
        async authorize(credentials) {
          const parsedCredentials = z
            .object({ email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(6) })
            .safeParse(credentials);

            if (parsedCredentials.success) {
                const { email, password } = parsedCredentials.data;
                const user = await getUser(email);
                if (!user) return null;
                const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
                if (passwordsMatch) return user;
              }
              console.log('Invalid credentials');
              return null;
        },
      }),
],

session: {
  strategy :'jwt',
},
pages: {
  signIn: '/auth/signin',
},



});

this is how i'm tring to get session information
//app/api/auth/session
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { authConfig } from '@/auth.config';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authConfig);

  if (session) {
    return NextResponse.json(session);
  } else {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'No active session' }, { status: 401 });
  }
}


I try to use the sessionPorvider un RootLayout component without success
import '@/app/ui/global.css';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  session,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  session: any;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


this is a component where i wanted to get information
import RootLayout from '@/app/layout';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getSession();

  return (
    <RootLayout session={session}>
      <div>The user_email is {session?.user?.email}</div>
    </RootLayout>
  );
}



try this
import { auth } from '@/auth';
then:
export async function GET() {
  const session = await auth();

...

{ getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next' in "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.20" is depricated.
